# I want to translate country name to english in using diffrent country locale Magento2?

Tags: zend-framework, magento2.4

I want to translate the country name in the dropdown cart page and checkout page I am using Thailand locale but I want to display the country name in English

I have add csv file in i18n

fore more detail please check screen shot [image]